# Log4net log file empty for webjob on azure

Tags: azure, log4net

Not sure if this is an issue with azure or my log4net config..

I've got a continuous webjob, that logs via log4net. I've set up a rolling file appender liks this:

```
<appender name="RollingFileAppender" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <threshold value="DEBUG"/>
  <file type="log4net.Util.PatternString"
        value=".\app_data\webjobs.log"/>
  <lockingModel type="log4net.Appender.FileAppender+MinimalLock" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %-5level %logger - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <rollingStyle value="Composite"/>
  <datePattern value="yyyyMMdd"/>
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="100"/>
  <maximumFileSize value="15MB"/>
</appender>
```

Locally, it all works, the log file is created and content is written.

When I publish to azure as a webjob, the log file is created, but nothing is written. It's empty. I've tried explicitly configurating log4net with

```
log4net.Config.XmlConfigurator.Configure(new FileInfo("log4net.config"));
```

But to no avail. Weirdly, I've got exactly the same setup for the website, and that logs perfectly fine.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah OK, so i needed to specify a full (not relative) path - it doesn't seem to work without that.

Comment: What was the absolute path you used?

Comment: @DavidThielen By default the site is d:\home\site\wwwroot - hope that helps

Comment: @MattRoberts Hi Matt. Have you had any issues with that? I wouldn't be surprised if that drive letter is not guaranteed, as Azure is a pretty hefty abstraction. Or has that drive letter remained solid?

Comment: The drive letter has remained solid.. I'm not sure it's guaranteed actually, but it's not something I would expect to change (famous last words?)

Comment: As of 8/2016, the path @MattRoberts stated still works.  Thanks!